# Reference to popup window in Chrome content script gets lost

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, popupwindow, content-script

In the content script of chrome extension, I would like to open a popup window and get the reference, so that I could send messages to the window, and close it in the `onbeforeunload` event.

However, it seems the reference only exists in the local scope, and it gets lost in any other closures.

e.g. If I use the following code in the content script:

```js
var popup = window.open("https://example.com/", 'popwin');
console.log("@1", popup);
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log("@2", popup);
}, 2000);
```

Here is what I see in the console window

> @1 Window {window: Window, self: Window, location: Location, closed: false, frames: Window, …}
>
> @2 global {}

---

And it's even the same if I use a global window property to store the reference, i.e.

```js
window.popup = window.open("https://example.com/", 'popwin');
console.log("@1", window.popup);
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log("@2", window.popup);
}, 2000);
```

> @1 Window {window: Window, self: Window, location: Location, closed: false, frames: Window, …}
>
> @2 global {}

Any idea about this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Both `popup` and `window.popup` are logging as expected in content script.

Comment: @elegant-user but in the second logging, it appeared as `global{}`, and I could not call the `popup.close()` there, is it normal?